# Django: minimize database hits with QuerSets

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got this custom admin command to remove some old records. [QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) are lazy so I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this code because at the moment there are four hits to database in `--dry-run` mode:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--dry-run', action='store_true')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        threshold = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(5)
        try:
            if options['dry_run']:
                queryset = Mointor.objects.filter(created__lt=threshold)
                if queryset.exists():
                    msg = f'{queryset.count()} record(s) will be deleted, from {queryset.first().created} to {queryset.last().created}'
                else:
                    msg = 'No records to delete'
            else:          
                Monitor.objects.filter(created__lt=threshold).delete()
                msg = 'OK'
        except Exception as e:
            raise CommandError(e)

        self.stdout.write(msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firsty do `count = queryset.count()` and then use it as `if` condition and insert inside string. So you will get rid of `exists` query. Also to find date range,  you can use `aggregate` with `Min` and `Max`,  so you have saved another query here. But as for me,  it is not really a problem.  Remember,  don't optimize prematurely unless you are sure you have a performance issue.

Comment: And another thing.  You can only aggregate and then check if the min or max is None,  so finally a single query)